# Debug visualizers for integral data types in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In my code base I have several instances of `long` variables that store a date (the number of days since a specific day).

Is there a way to create a visualizer in VS2010 so that when debugging I can get the actual date next to the `long` value?
I can't find much documentation on the visualizers  besides basic stuff. Specifically:

Is it possible to create visualizers for integral types? (and keep the initial value visible)

Is it possible to do some small computations in the visualizer ? (I need to compute a string that corresponds to the date that my `long` refers to)

Comment: Why is a date a `long` and not a `date`? (That would make the first question moot)

Comment: You mean as a typedef or as a class? I know that's the logical solution but this is an old codebase of 10k files, and it's not my job to refactor it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a visualiser for a this struct:

```
struct DaysAfter
{
    long mDays;
};
```

Then c-cast what you need to this type in the debugger.

```
*(DaysAfter*)&this->m_date
```